# Getting access token for external provider's APIs in IdentityServer3

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect

We have Identity Server set up for access to our internal APIs. We have a new JavaScript client that would like to in one request get id and access tokens for our internal APIs, and an access token for calling APIs directly from the external identity provider (in this case, Google). I was thinking if it was possible to get it I could return it as a claim in our id_token.

Is this supported? I set the response type on the identity provider to "id_token token", and I can see that the access token is getting returned to Identity Server, but I don't see it on the context of any of the user service methods.

Comment: When you say "calling APIs directly from the external identity provider", do you mean calling your own APIs but with a token obtained via authenticating with Google? I would suggest looking at some of the samples and following them through which helped me when I was trying to set this up: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples

Comment: This particular client has a need to call both our APIs (with our access token) and Google APIs (with a Google access token). It would always authenticate using Google as the IDP. I didn't see anything in the samples to cover this scenario (which may be an indicator that it's not possible / not recommended)

Answer (score 1):

> and an access token for calling APIs directly from the external identity provider (in this case, Google)

Normally the use of IdentityServer is meant to abstract and shield your app from having to know which upstream identity provider the user used. But having said this, you could capture the google access token at signin time at IdenittyServer. One idea is to put it into the database, then in the GetProfileData API on the user service put it into the issued claims back to the app.

Comment: I was wondering where in the pipeline I might be able to intercept the access token from Google - it's not passed to AuthenticateExternalAsync, for example.

Comment: In the middleware -- they have events that fire

Comment: @Igaud This is in the Owin middleware. See the source code for this here http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google/GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler.cs

Brock Allen - How do we capture the token? Where in IdentityServer could we capture this value? I hope to not create a subclass of the GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler as that would be a pain! Thanks!